# How do I print the full array of correlation outputs in python? Also, if you could inform me how to interpret them, that would be wonderful/

Tags: python, arrays, correlation, cross-correlation

Array 1: 21 elements
Array 2: 21 elements

`a = np.correlate (array 1, array 2, 'full') /np.dot(abs(array 1), abs (array 2), 'full')`

The results are indexed (easier to interpret for myself). Im trying to print out the full results in the console. However, i only get `[ 0.03996053  0.0787816   0.11639996 ...,  0.16535523  0.11071052
  0.05387852]`

I checked the length of(a) out  of curiosity on top of this and it says there are 41 elements?

There are two key problems for myself. One, why is there 41 elements in the results? Two, how do i print the full array?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there 41 elements in the results?

In the doc for [`np.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy.convolve) (which is referred to by the [`np.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) doc) for mode "full":

> This returns the convolution at each point of overlap, with an output shape of (N+M-1,).

In your case, N and M are both 21 (both arrays are 21 elements as you said), so `(21 + 21 - 1) = 41`

As far as the printing goes, you might be getting limited by whatever terminal/display you're using? I'm not able to replicate the truncated printout (although it's what `numpy` does to represent *large* arrays).

```
>>> a
array([0.        , 0.00696864, 0.02055749, 0.04041812, 0.06620209,
       0.09756098, 0.13414634, 0.17560976, 0.22160279, 0.271777  ,
       0.32578397, 0.38327526, 0.44390244, 0.50731707, 0.57317073,
       0.64111498, 0.71080139, 0.78188153, 0.85400697, 0.92682927,
       1.        , 0.92682927, 0.85400697, 0.78188153, 0.71080139,
       0.64111498, 0.57317073, 0.50731707, 0.44390244, 0.38327526,
       0.32578397, 0.271777  , 0.22160279, 0.17560976, 0.13414634,
       0.09756098, 0.06620209, 0.04041812, 0.02055749, 0.00696864,
       0.        ])
```

To get around that though, you could print each of the 41 elements in the array:

```
>>> for value in a:
>>>     print(a)
0.0
0.006968641114982578
0.020557491289198607
0.04041811846689895
0.06620209059233449
0.0975609756097561
0.13414634146341464
0.17560975609756097
0.221602787456446
0.27177700348432055
0.32578397212543553
0.3832752613240418
0.44390243902439025
0.5073170731707317
0.573170731707317
0.6411149825783972
0.710801393728223
0.7818815331010452
0.854006968641115
0.926829268292683
1.0
0.926829268292683
0.854006968641115
0.7818815331010452
0.710801393728223
0.6411149825783972
0.573170731707317
0.5073170731707317
0.44390243902439025
0.3832752613240418
0.32578397212543553
0.27177700348432055
0.221602787456446
0.17560975609756097
0.13414634146341464
0.0975609756097561
0.06620209059233449
0.04041811846689895
0.020557491289198607
0.006968641114982578
0.0
```